# Working with json to consume a dot net web service from android

Tags: android, web-services

How to consume this web service  "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx" in android using JSON.So far i searched and found JSON is he best approach to consume a web service.

But i cannot find any good samples from Google.

Can any one please give me the step by step method or at-least give me one sample program or code to consume this web service.

Suggestions please!..

Comment: is your web service returning JSON?

Answer (score 1):

May be this http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/ can help
or http://www.androidsnippets.com/retrieve-json-from-a-rest-web-service